# install FFMPEG on PHP 7.0.6 - Xampp

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, php-7, video-conversion

I am new to php. I am trying to convert video uploaded by the user.
Somehow, I have done all the php work except conversion. I came to know about **FFMPEG**, I have installed it and tried with CLI and it worked perfect.

When I tried it in ph using **shell_exec()** command. It gives me nothing, Then by google, I should activate the extension of ffmpeg in my php.ini file.

```
shell_exec("ffmpeg -i video/Wildlife.wmv video/output.mp4");
```

I have googled but there is no help regarding this php version.
Any idea or guideline will be very helpful.

This may be a duplicate question but there is nothing with php 7 version on stackoverflow.

Comment: Start independent process within your php code (ffmpeg in your case). And pass arguements through your php code.

Answer (score 0):

FFMPEG is standalone library. You don't have to install any php extensions.
Try run your command directly from bash shell and check the results.

Problem may be caused by corrupted FFMPEG installation.

Another problem may be with your php configuration.
You can find in documetation informaction, that shell_exec function is disabled, when you use safe mode.

Check also `disable_functions` entry in your php.ini file.

Comment: I have checked disable_functions and it says no value for **Local value** and **Master value** ... Also I have tried this `if(function_exists('shell_exec')) {
    echo "exec is enabled";
}`, and shell_exec function is enabled.

Comment: I have tried this command `ffmpeg -i video/Wildlife.wmv video/output.mp4` on my cmd, and it worked perfect

Comment: I checked it on my php 7.0.9 and it works... :/ but what your php error.log ? Is there also no entries ?